# I am unable to find bin folder in "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache"

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

After running this command in cmd "npm install -g firebase-tools"
i have to create a enviromental variable, then i go to this path "C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache"
to get bin folder but i couldn't find any bin folder right there. Anyone what i have to get bin folder.

any authentic way to get that folder with detail steps.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Recommend sending a question to the author of the installation instructions.